# Pluralize quote ending in punctuation

Tags: grammar, punctuation, writing-style, quotations, quotation-marks

I (think I) know how to pluralize an indirect quote, *e.g.*,

> Their survey answers were limited to yeses and nos.

But how do I pluralize a direct quote ending in a punctuation mark? Am I even allowed to retain the punctuation mark for emphasis?

In other words, would the correct form(s) be:

> 1. There was no shortage of "How do you do?"s and "Let's do lunch!"es at the networking event.
> 2. There was no shortage of "How do you do"s and "Let's do lunch"es at the networking event.
> 3. There was no shortage of how-do-you-dos and let's-do-lunches at the networking event.
> 4. *[something else altogether]*

Does the number of correct forms change when I elect to italicize quotes, rather than demarcate them with quotation marks?

**A/N:** I was trying to keep my example short, but I do realize that "how-do-you-do" is already an [established phrase](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/89012?rskey=c1jaWZ&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid). Hyphenation seems unwieldy, however, if the quote were longer.

Comment: Since you are choosing an informal, even quirky, style, I don't see how a charge of 'unacceptable' could be made to stick. A workaround is << There was no shortage of people ready with "How do you do?" and "Let's do lunch!" at the networking event. >>

Comment: I like option 3 best. But I would either italicise or put in quotes *how-do-you-dos* and *let's-do-lunches*. I might also use an apostrophe when pluralising words like *do* and *no* - *do's* and *no's*. I feel sure it has been recommended on this site before.

Comment: @WS2 I prefer 2 to 3, mainly because it makes clear that it is the expressions which are pluralised and not the 'do' and the 'lunch'. However I think its a matter of personal preference.

Comment: I like 3 best.  And I like using italics - they make it simple and clear.  I think I prefer  the pluralising suffixes not to be italicised - "... shortage of *How-do-you-do*-s and *Let's do lunch*-es at the networking event."  I can't decide whether it's clearer using a dash to separate the two text types, or simply running them together.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend #3, with the italicization suggested in the comments.

As you point out, *how-do-you-do* is a headword in [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/how-do-you-do) and even gives the plural as *how-do-you-dos*.

> 1.
>   a greeting; salutation:
>   She smiled and gave him a how-do-you-do fit for a king.

Likewise, it is listed in [the Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/89012?rskey=4aTPPG&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid):

> 2. n. Used as a name for the inquiry (which is often used as a mere greeting or salutation); = how-do-ye phr. and n. 2. (In quot. 1632   applied to the inquirer.)

*Let's-do-lunches* will be understood by analogy.

As for longer phrases, it seems increasingly unlikely there would be a lot of people saying exactly "Why hello sir I trust you have met my wife, Martha." If there were, you could use *Why-hello-sir,-I-trust-you-have-met-my-wife,-Marthas* for comedic effect.

Answer (score 0):

I am the weirdo who prefers and practices #1.  This is predicated on a belief that quoted punctuation should be considered entirely separately from outer-sentence punctuation.  Thus to my nerd mind, the following is proper:

- The words I heard were, "What's that sound?".

I know many cringe at seeing both the question mark and a period, but the quote is a question, and the sentence is not.  Once there, it is a natural extension to say:

- Due to the creaking of the house, there were many "What's that sound?"s heard throughout the evening.